# Default Browser Red Border CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to figure out how to create a red border box for when people do not enter information for required fields. Is there a way to make every browser have the default input required red outline box?

**Like this:**
[image]

The code I have been working on is not as appealing to the eye as the border I desire. Does anyone know how to recreate the border above?

```
input.error {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example and I will accept as the answer if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it can be done with the outline :

```
<input type=text style="outline:2px solid #f77; outline-offset:-1px ">
<select style="outline:2px solid #f77; outline-offset:-1px ">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q45yuno8/

Comment: the corners seem rounded also do you know how to do that? Sorry I am very new to css

Comment: @KTE Not in each browser they appear as rounded and you cannot determine their roundness by CSS means. As an option you can apply your own styles to inputs with border-radius + box-shadow if needed. In this case they will look the same in all browsers. Check samples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Comment: i keep trying that radius but am not very successful.. I wonder how they did it because its not the inputs that are rounded only the red outline in mozilla